# Write the output of a find command within a loop to a file

Tags: find, io-redirection

I have a `find` command nested within a loop and I want to write the output to a file and be able to see it live as well. But every approach I have tried so far has failed to fulfill this.

My `while` command is this:

```
while read -r LINE; do find "$LINE" -name "*Bop*" ; done < /drives/d/dirs_to_search.txt
```

When I run the command above, **I can see the list of matching sub-directories** printed into my terminal window. I want to **keep seeing this list of matches**, but **at the same time write them to a file**.

And the approaches I have tried so far to write the output of `find` to a file named `matched_subdirs`:

```
while read -r LINE; do find "$LINE" -name "*Bop*" | tee /drives/d/matched_subdirs.txt ; done < /drives/d/dirs_to_search.txt

while read -r LINE; do find "$LINE" -name "*Bop*" ; done < /drives/d/dirs_to_search.txt | tee /drives/d/matched_subdirs.txt

while read -r LINE; do find "$LINE" -name "*Bop*" -print; done < /drives/d/dirs_to_search.txt | tee /drives/d/matched_subdirs.txt

while read -r LINE; do find "$LINE" -name "*Bop*" > /drives/d/matched_subdirs.txt ; done < /drives/d/dirs_to_search.txt

while read -r LINE; do find "$LINE" -name "*Bop*"; done < /drives/d/dirs_to_search.txt > /drives/d/matched_subdirs.txt
```

Comment: Some of those should work. Actually, all of them should work, it's just that some of them would only return the last result because you keep overwriting the file. What actually happens when you try the second approach, for instance? That one should be fine.

Comment: What are you going to do with the output later? It would be safer to use the found pathnames directly from within `find` to do what you need to de with them.

Comment: `<` redirects `stdin` (input).

Comment: @Kusalananda, I intend to use them in an `rsync` loop--a loop similar to the one in my post above--later on.

Comment: @terdon, When I try the second approach (with `tee` at the end), I see nothing printed to the screen. Whereas normally when I run that same command without the ending pipe, I see a lot of matched sub-directories immediately printed onto the terminal.

Comment: @vivoru I see no reason to use find at all then as it's pretty straight forward to get rsync to do the work. I'll update my answer with that as soon as I'm back at a computer.

Comment: Isn't `find` however much faster than `rsync` when using wildcards and recursing into thousands and thousands of sub-directories with each of them containing thousands of files? That was one of the main reasons I switched to `find`. `rsync` was taking forever to build the list.. Whereas with a small benchmark I found out that it's much faster to find the exact name of directories matched with `find` and then pass them over to `rsync`.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What you describe is very odd, the `tee` should work (and does, on my Arch).

Comment: It was indeed a problem caused by the operating system (or perhaps corrupted package installation). I was using `cygwin` on Windows. Now I switched to `Ubuntu` and the same command is working without a problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) Now I can remove my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The commands that you have shown *should*, [as terdon says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455095/write-the-output-of-a-find-command-within-a-loop-to-a-file#comment827177_455095), work.

An alternative that gets rid of `tee`:

```
rm -f /drives/d/matched_subdirs.txt
while IFS= read -r pathname; do
    find "$pathname" -name '*Bop*' -print \
        -exec sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@" >>matched' sh {} +
done <dirlist
```

This would let `find` print the found pathnames for you to look at, and then use an embedded shell script for writing them to the result file.

I'm a tiny bit worried about what you're intending to do with the pathnames in the output file. If you're intending to use them for looping over later, then it would be better to do so from within `find` directly.  You would have issues with strange filenames containing embedded newlines otherwise.

---

[In comments you say](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/299496/vivoru) that you intend to use the found pathnames in a loop to run `rsync`.  Calling `rsync` for each pathnames would be *very* slow, and you'd be better doing this with `rsync` directly:

```
while IFS= read -r pathname; do
    rsync -avR --include='*/' --include='*Bop*' --exclude='*' --prune-empty-dirs "$pathname" target
done <dirlist
```

Here, `dirlist` is a file with your directories.

Example:

```
$ tree
.
|-- dirlist
`-- source
    |-- a
    |   |-- dir-1
    |   |   |-- somefile_Bop_here
    |   |   `-- someotherfile
    |   |-- dir-2
    |   |   |-- somefile_Bop_here
    |   |   `-- someotherfile
    |   `-- dir-3
    |       |-- somefile_Bop_here
    |       `-- someotherfile
    |-- b
    |   |-- dir-1
    |   |   |-- somefile_Bop_here
    |   |   `-- someotherfile
    |   |-- dir-2
    |   |   |-- somefile_Bop_here
    |   |   `-- someotherfile
    |   `-- dir-3
    |       |-- somefile_Bop_here
    |       `-- someotherfile
    `-- c
        |-- dir-1
        |   |-- somefile_Bop_here
        |   `-- someotherfile
        |-- dir-2
        |   |-- somefile_Bop_here
        |   `-- someotherfile
        `-- dir-3
            |-- somefile_Bop_here
            `-- someotherfile

13 directories, 19 files
```

```
$ cat dirlist
source/a
source/b/dir-2
```

(running loop here)

```
$ tree target
target
`-- source
    |-- a
    |   |-- dir-1
    |   |   `-- somefile_Bop_here
    |   |-- dir-2
    |   |   `-- somefile_Bop_here
    |   `-- dir-3
    |       `-- somefile_Bop_here
    `-- b
        `-- dir-2
            `-- somefile_Bop_here

7 directories, 4 files
```

I chose to use `-R` (`--relative`). Without it, I would have gotten

```
target
|-- a
|   |-- dir-1
|   |   `-- somefile_Bop_here
|   |-- dir-2
|   |   `-- somefile_Bop_here
|   `-- dir-3
|       `-- somefile_Bop_here
`-- dir-2
    `-- somefile_Bop_here
```